# Formally proving that function is locally bounded in range

Tags: calculus

I have the following definition of Local boundedness:

function $f(x)$ in $I\subseteq R$ called local bounded if for every $x_0\in I$ exists $\delta>0$ so $f(x)$ is bounded in $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$.

I'm trying to take a small example of $f(x)=x$ in $I=[-2,2]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and prove that it is local bounded in that range.

I struggling to prove it formally. How can I prove it formally?

Answer (score 0):

$|f(x)| \leq 4$ so any $\delta $ will do.

Comment: I understand that but how can I show it formally?

Comment: What I have written is  a complete formal proof. Just apply the definition. Take any $x_0$ and any $\delta >0$ and note that $f$ is bounded by $4$ in absolute value on $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$. @vesii